# Calcular valores com Inputy type="range" e JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, input

Caros, olá.

Estou precisando fazer alguns cálculos utilizando o input type="range", mas não estou conseguindo rodar o código na minha maquina, apenas em editores online e gostaria de saber por que isso ocorre?
Utilizo windows 10 e o editor de texto é o notepad++.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

<script>
function generateResult() {
  var range1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('range1').value);
  var range2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('range2').value);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = range1 + range2;
}

document.getElementById('range1').addEventListener('change', function(){
  generateResult();
});

document.getElementById('range2').addEventListener('change', function(){
  generateResult();
});

</script>

<div>
   Range
   <input type="range"  class="observe" id="range1">
   <input type="range"  class="observe" id="range2">
</div>

<div>
   Resultado
   <div id="result"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Olá Marck pode explicar melhor *"fazer alguns cálculos"* e o quer dizer com *"não estou conseguindo rodar o código"*? qual erro, resultado esperado, etc?

Comment: Olá, referente ao calculo seria somar, dividir e etc.

Comment: Você tem que saber exatemente o que quer fazer, dê exemplos concretos dos vários cálculos que quer fazer e onde eles entrariam na página. Como nota, não faça `+range1.value` para converter para inteiro a menos que esteja numa competição de codegolf.

Comment: Vamos lá, a questão dos "cálculos" eu já consegui fazer, que é somar os dois inputs, mas eu não to conseguindo rodar eles a não ser por editores online como o que é disponível pelo  stackoverflow

Comment: Outro erro que encontrei: Na linha result.innerHTML, a não ser que você tenha atribuido algum valor a alguma variável chamada result, ele deve apresentar algum erro. Deveria ser `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = //atribuição`

Comment: Então, o código funciona no JSFiddle mas não local

Comment: Creio que se você se focar em resolver os erros de sintaxe e se preocupar menos com onde funciona e onde não funciona você vai chegar na resposta mais cedo.

Comment: Fiz as alterações que você tinha informado mas continua sem funcionar

Comment: Estou fazendo um código para colocar na resposta e aí você vai poder ver onde errou, aguarde um momento

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta fazer desta forma:

Html:

```
<div id="ranges">
   Range
   <input type="range"  class="observe" id="range1">
   <input type="range"  class="observe" id="range2">
</div>

<div>
   Resultado
   <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function generateResult() {
  var range1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('range1').value);
  var range2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('range2').value);
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = range1 + range2;
}

document.getElementById('ranges').addEventListener('change', generateResult);
```

Não é a melhor forma de se fazer, mas funciona. Tenta rodar no seu computador.
Exemplo no codepen: https://codepen.io/matt1991/pen/xJQgrb?editors=1010

Edit: Tentei fazer uma coisa pra deixar mais simples mas não funcionou, reverti pro código anterior.
Edit2: Melhorado um pouco o código

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, eu editei a pergunta de como fiz.

Comment: Que erro aparece no console? O que ocorre?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at index.html:15

Comment: Coloca o javascript após todo o html, no final do body e tenta de novo.

Comment: Cara, era isso mesmo, muito obrigado

Comment: O erro ocorreu por que você tentou pegar o valor de um input que não tinha sido criado ainda. O html executa o código de cima pra baixo.
Sempre que você for se referir a algo no html, use o `document.getElementById('id do valor')`, a não ser que você atribua esse valor a uma variável pra facilitar a leitura do codigo como fiz com os ranges. Se possível, marque minha resposta como a solução, a não ser que queira esperar outro código melhor (que com certeza existe)